# Best way to remove an Element from the DOM if it exists

Tags: javascript, validation, dom

I've been getting back into Javascript lately, and I've created this simple form validation as practice. I'm wondering what the best way to go about something, logically would be. Take a look at this code:

```
var regName = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regEmail = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regUserName = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regPassword = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

//span tags multiply when you keep hitting the submit button. .textContent doesn't seem to work, and even if it did it's kind of a cheap work around because the tags will still be there, you just wont see them. I need to check if the tag exists (before the if statement) and if it does, remove it.

var validate = {
  validateName: function() {
    var fName = document.getElementById('fName');
    var nameContainer = document.querySelector('#nameContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.createElement('span');

    nameContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
    fName.classList.remove('errorBorder');

    if (fName.value.match(regName)) {
      console.log('Name Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.innerHTML = '*checkmark*';
    } else if(fName.value === '') {
      console.log('input is empty');
    } else {
      console.log('Name Invalid');
      fName.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.innerHTML = '*invalid input';
    }
  },
  validateEmail: function() {
    var fEmail = document.getElementById('fEmail');
    var emailContainer = document.querySelector('#emailContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.createElement('span');

    emailContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
    fEmail.classList.remove('errorBorder');

    if (fEmail.value.match(regEmail)) {
      console.log('Email Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('Email Invalid');
      fEmail.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';

    }
  },
  validateUserName: function() {
    var fUserName = document.getElementById('fUserName');
    var userNameContainer = document.querySelector('#userNameContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.createElement('span');

    userNameContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
    fUserName.classList.remove('errorBorder');

    if (fUserName.value.match(regUserName)) {
      console.log('User Name Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('User Name Invalid');
      fUserName.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';
    }
  },
  validatePassword: function() {
    var fPassword = document.getElementById('fPassword');
    var passwordContainer = document.querySelector('#passwordContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.createElement('span');

    passwordContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
    fPassword.classList.remove('errorBorder');

    if (fPassword.value.match(regPassword)) {
      console.log('Passowrd Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('Passowrd Invalid');
      fPassword.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';
    }
  }
};

function onSubmit() {
  validate.validateName();
  validate.validateEmail();
  validate.validateUserName();
  validate.validatePassword();
}
```

```html
    <form onsubmit="return false">

      <div id="nameContainer">
        <label>Full Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fName" />
      </div>

      <div id="emailContainer">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fEmail" />
      </div>

      <div id="userNameContainer">
        <label>User Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fUserName" />
      </div>

      <div id="passwordContainer">
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="password" id="fPassword" />
      </div>

      <br />

      <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="onSubmit()" />

    </form>
```

If you take a look at my my code, you'll see there are 4 fields and a submit button. Right now the JavaScript code just returns either "checkmark" or "invalid input" inside  tags next tot he input fields depending on if the input fields are populated or not.

The issues I'm having is, if you hit the submit button more than once (running all the functions agani), the

I would like only the most recent sets of span tags to show. Or in other words, before inserting the span tags, to check if they exist in the DOM and delete them if they do.

Comment: Please don't post links to code on 3rd party sites. If those links become dead over time, then your question becomes unintelligible. Just create a code snippet right here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it above.

Comment: You ask for the best way to go about something and then you ask how to keep the `span` elements updated using the worst possible technique (adding them to the DOM and removing them constantly). The best solution is to have them statically in the DOM because you need them in every case and just update their values. The even better solution is to condense the 4 validation functions (which are 99% similar) into just one. See my answer below for both of those solutions.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With the HTML structure that you have, the simplest way to know if there is a `span` element just after the current `input` element that is being validated is to just check the `nextElementSibling` of the `input` element to see if it is a `span`. If it is, then you need to remove the `nextElementSibling` and if not, you can add it.

For example, in your first validation:

```
var fName = document.getElementById('fName');
// .getElementById() is faster than .querySelector() when looking for id's
var nameContainer = document.getElementById('nameContainer');

// Is the next element sibling of the field a span?
if(nameContainer.nextElementSibling.nodeName === "SPAN"){
  // span already exists - remove it
  nameContainer.parentNode.removeChild(nameContainer.nextElementSibling);
} else {
  // span does not exist - create and add it
  var infoSpan = document.createElement('span');
  nameContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
}
```

Having said that, this is entirely unnecessary and hinders performance because you are modifying the DOM over and over.

Since you need a `span` no matter what, just create them statically in the HTML and then just update their `textContent` (don't use `.innerHTML` unless you have HTML to be parsed).

```js
var regName = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regEmail = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regUserName = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regPassword = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

var validate = {
  validateName: function() {
    var fName = document.getElementById('fName');
    var nameContainer = document.querySelector('#nameContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.getElementById('nameInfo');
    fName.classList.remove('errorBorder');

    if (fName.value.match(regName)) {
      console.log('Name Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else if(fName.value === '') {
      console.log('input is empty');
    } else {
      console.log('Name Invalid');
      fName.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';
    }
  },
  validateEmail: function() {
    var fEmail = document.getElementById('fEmail');
    var emailContainer = document.querySelector('#emailContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.getElementById('emailInfo');
    
    fEmail.classList.remove('errorBorder');
    
    if (fEmail.value.match(regEmail)) {
      console.log('Email Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('Email Invalid');
      fEmail.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';

    }
  },
  validateUserName: function() {
    var fUserName = document.getElementById('fUserName');
    var userNameContainer = document.querySelector('#userNameContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.getElementById('userNameInfo');
    
    fUserName.classList.remove('errorBorder');

    if (fUserName.value.match(regUserName)) {
      console.log('User Name Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('User Name Invalid');
      fUserName.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';
    }
  },
  validatePassword: function() {
    var fPassword = document.getElementById('fPassword');
    var passwordContainer = document.querySelector('#passwordContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.getElementById('passwordInfo');
    
    fPassword.classList.remove('errorBorder');

    if (fPassword.value.match(regPassword)) {
      console.log('Passowrd Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('Passowrd Invalid');
      fPassword.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';
    }
  }
};

function onSubmit() {
  validate.validateName();
  validate.validateEmail();
  validate.validateUserName();
  validate.validatePassword();
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

label, span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

form div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
}

.errorBorder {
  border: thin red solid;
}

span.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

span.checkmark {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
      
      <div id="nameContainer">
        <label>Full Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fName"><span id="nameInfo"></span>
      </div>
      
      <div id="emailContainer">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fEmail"><span id="emailInfo"></span>
      </div>
      
      <div id="userNameContainer">
        <label>User Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fUserName"><span id="userNameInfo"></span>
      </div>
      
      <div id="passwordContainer">
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="password" id="fPassword"><span id="passwordInfo"></span>
      </div>
      
      <br />
      
      <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="onSubmit()">
      
    </form>
```

You may also want to reconsider this entire design given that each of your validation functions is essentially the same, except for the regular expression that it uses to determine validity. Additionally, you could also just use the HTML5 form fields that have built-in validation or a full API for you to work from.

```js
// Do all event wiring in JavaScript, not with HTML event attributes
// And, form validation should be done on the form's submit event and
// the form submission should be cancelled via the event object that
// is automatically passed to the function
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(evt){

  // Store regular expressions in an object
  var regs = {
    regName : /^[A-Za-z]+$/,
    regEmail : /^[A-Za-z]+$/,
    regUserName : /^[A-Za-z]+$/,
    regPassword : /^[A-Za-z]+$/
  };
    
  var valid = true;  // Set up variable to track any errors

  // Gather up all the fields to be validated into an array.
  var fieldsToValidate = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".validate"));
  
  // Loop over each of the fields to be validated
  fieldsToValidate.forEach(function(field, index){
    var message = "";
    var infoSpan = field.nextElementSibling;
    
    // Test the field against the corresponding regular expression in the object
    if(field.value.match(regs[Object.keys(regs)[index]])){
      message = "*checkmark*";
      infoSpan.classList.remove("error");      
      infoSpan.classList.add("checkmark");
    } else {
      valid = false;
      message = "*error*";
      infoSpan.classList.remove("checkmark");    
      infoSpan.classList.add("error");       
    }

    infoSpan.textContent = message; 
  });
    
  // If there were any errors, prevent the form from being submitted
  if(!valid){ evt.preventDefault(); }
});
```

```css
label, span { font-family: sans-serif; }
label { font-size: 14px; display: inline-block; width: 85px; }
form div { margin: 10px 0; }
.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: thin red solid; 
}
.checkmark {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form>    
  <div>
    <label>Full Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="fName" class="validate"><span id="nameInfo"></span>
  </div>
      
  <div>
    <label>Email: </label>
    <input type="text" id="fEmail" class="validate"><span id="emailInfo"></span>
  </div>
      
  <div>
    <label>User Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="fUserName" class="validate"><span id="userNameInfo"></span>
  </div>
      
  <div>
    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="fPassword" class="validate"><span id="passwordInfo"></span>
  </div>
      
  <div><input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Combining everything into one function seems like a more more efficient way to go about this. I'll work towards this :)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the plaker and added a function that cleans all errors before submitting. That was missing in your code: https://plnkr.co/edit/tIvl5rplqAP53ylzLLtf?p=preview

```
function cleanErrors() {
  var allErrors = document.querySelectorAll('form input + span');
  for (var i=0; i < allErrors.length; i++) {
    console.log('error',allErrors[i]);
    allErrors[i].parentNode.removeChild(allErrors[i]);
  }
}
function onSubmit() {
  cleanErrors();
  validate.validateName();
  validate.validateEmail();
  validate.validateUserName();
  validate.validatePassword();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is assign the info div an ID, that way you can first try to get an existing infospan. Then check if it exists, if it does just use it instead, if it doesn't create it.

```js
//var regName = /^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$/;
//var regEmail = /\w{1-20}@\w{1-10}.\w{2-3}/;
//var regUserName = /^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,20}$/;
//var regPassword = /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_-]{6,20}$/; 

var regName = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regEmail = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regUserName = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var regPassword = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

//span tags multiply when you keep hitting the submit button. .textContent doesn't seem to work, and even if it did it's kind of a cheap work around because the tags will still be there, you just wont see them. I need to check if the tag exists (before the if statement) and if it does, remove it.

var validate = {
  validateName: function() {
    var fName = document.getElementById('fName');
    var nameContainer = document.querySelector('#nameContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.getElementById('fNameInfo');
    
    if (!infoSpan) {
      infoSpan = document.createElement('span');
      infoSpan.id = 'fNameInfo';
      nameContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
    }
  
    
    fName.classList.remove('errorBorder');
    infoSpan.classList.remove('checkmark');
    infoSpan.classList.remove('error');

    if (fName.value.match(regName)) {
      console.log('Name Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.innerHTML = '*checkmark*';
    } else if(fName.value === '') {
      console.log('input is empty');
    } else {
      console.log('Name Invalid');
      fName.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.innerHTML = '*invalid input';
    }
  },
  validateEmail: function() {
    var fEmail = document.getElementById('fEmail');
    var emailContainer = document.querySelector('#emailContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.getElementById('fEmailInfo');
    
    if (!infoSpan) {
      infoSpan = document.createElement('span');
      infoSpan.id = 'fEmailInfo';
      emailContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
    }
    
    fEmail.classList.remove('errorBorder');
    infoSpan.classList.remove('checkmark');
    infoSpan.classList.remove('error');
    
    if (fEmail.value.match(regEmail)) {
      console.log('Email Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('Email Invalid');
      fEmail.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';

    }
  },
  validateUserName: function() {
    var fUserName = document.getElementById('fUserName');
    var userNameContainer = document.querySelector('#userNameContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.getElementById('fUserNameInfo');
    
    if (!infoSpan) {
      infoSpan = document.createElement('span');
      infoSpan.id = 'fUserNameInfo';
      userNameContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
    }
    
    fUserName.classList.remove('errorBorder');
    infoSpan.classList.remove('checkmark');
    infoSpan.classList.remove('error');

    if (fUserName.value.match(regUserName)) {
      console.log('User Name Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('User Name Invalid');
      fUserName.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';
    }
  },
  validatePassword: function() {
    var fPassword = document.getElementById('fPassword');
    var passwordContainer = document.querySelector('#passwordContainer');
    var infoSpan = document.getElementById('fPasswordInfo');
    
    if (!infoSpan) {
      infoSpan = document.createElement('span');
      infoSpan.id = 'fPasswordInfo';
      passwordContainer.appendChild(infoSpan);
    }
    
    fPassword.classList.remove('errorBorder');
    infoSpan.classList.remove('checkmark');
    infoSpan.classList.remove('error');

    if (fPassword.value.match(regPassword)) {
      console.log('Passowrd Valid');
      infoSpan.classList.add('checkmark');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*checkmark*';
    } else {
      console.log('Passowrd Invalid');
      fPassword.classList.add('errorBorder');
      infoSpan.classList.add('error');
      infoSpan.textContent = '*invalid input';
    }
  }
};

function onSubmit() {
  validate.validateName();
  validate.validateEmail();
  validate.validateUserName();
  validate.validatePassword();
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

label, span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

form div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
}

.errorBorder {
  border: thin red solid;
}

span.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

span.checkmark {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
      
      <div id="nameContainer">
        <label>Full Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fName" />
      </div>
      
      <div id="emailContainer">
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fEmail" />
      </div>
      
      <div id="userNameContainer">
        <label>User Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="fUserName" />
      </div>
      
      <div id="passwordContainer">
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="password" id="fPassword" />
      </div>
      
      <br />
      
      <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="onSubmit()" />
      
    </form>
```